# Bootstrap - Set Breakpoint For Toggle Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 i would like to have the toggle menu for all viewports smaller than 992px.

What is the most appropriate way of achieving this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in its LESS file and build by yourself instead of using the precompiled one.

`@grid-float-breakpoint` is the point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed. It's default value is `@screen-sm-min` which is `@screen-sm` = 768px. You can change it to `@screen-md-min` which is `@screen-md` = 992px, which happens to be the value you want.

Bootstrap's official website provides a customize page for you to get it done without touching the LESS source itself. See: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: I see, i tried `.navbar-toggle{
    @max-width: 992px;
}`